# Unable to download NSE Archives data using python and golang

Tags: python-3.x, go, https, python-requests

I am trying to get csv data for the banned scripts in NSE using link:
https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/fo/fo_secban.csv
When I paste this url in browser I am able to get the data, even from postman also I am able to get the data.

I tried with both golang and python
It is getting in forever loop in python and in golang it is giving me http2StreamError

```
import requests

url = "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/fo/fo_secban.csv"
headers = {}

try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an HTTPError for bad responses
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error during request: {e}")
else:
    print(response.text)
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    // Specify the URL you want to call
    url := "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/content/fo/fo_secban.csv"

    // Make the HTTP GET request
    response, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error making GET request: %s\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    // Read the response body
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading response body: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Print the response body as a string
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

I tried with both golang and python3